# Laravel/Eloquent: Iterate over topics that have articles with approved comments

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

This is my data structure:

Models:

- `Topic` `hasMany` `Article`
- `Article` `belongsTo` `Topic` and `hasMany` `Comment`
- `Comment` `belongsTo` `Article`
- Additionally, `Topic` `hasManyThrough` `Comment` (via `Article`)

DB tables:

- `topics`: int `id`, string `label`
- `articles`: int `id`, string `content`, int `topic_id`(foreign key)
- `comments`: int `id`, string `content`, boolean `approved`, int `article_id`(foreign key)

Now, I want to iterate over all `topics` that have `articles` with `approved` `comments`.

```
@FOREACH ($topics->where(...) as $topic)
  <div> 
    {{ $topic->label }} has {{ $topic->articles->count() }} articles with approved comments.
  </div>
  ...
@ENDFOREACH
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to define the `where`-clause. Or should it be a `when`-clause? [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections#available-methods) is a list of the methods available for Laravel Collections.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any relations defined in the models?

Comment: Yes, I revised my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$topics = Topic::whereHas('articles', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
        $query->where('approved', true);
    });
})->get();

@foreach ($topics as $topic)
<div>
    {{ $topic->label }} has {{ $topic->articles->count() }} articles with approved comments.
</div>
@endforeach
```

Alternatively you could use your `hasManyThrough` relation in a similar way, but I don't have an example to try it out.

Comment: Thanks. I added the first part to my `IndexController` and the latter one to `index.blade.php`. Unfortunately, no topics are displayed. `$topics->count()`yields `2` and `get_class($topics)`yields `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. Shouldn't that be `Topic`instead?

Comment: @BarretWallace, my mistake, forgot to add `->get()` at the end of the query. Updated the answer above.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I also was able to use the `hasManyThrough`relation in order to have a shorter query.